# /proc/self/fd/2 can not be accessed under `sudo -u other_user`

Tags: sudo, pty

I often use `tee /proc/self/fd/2` to show something both to stdout and stderr, capture stdout, while still keep all output to stderr.

E.g., I have a `do.sh`:

```
STD_OUT_STR=$(CMD ARGS ... 2>&1 | tee /proc/self/fd/2)
# handle STD_OUT_STR ...
...
```

This works pretty well.

e.g.,

```
./do.sh
```

which essentially runs like this:

```
bash -c 'echo hi | tee /proc/self/fd/2'
```

outputs

```
hi
hi
```

However, one day I run it under `sudo -u A_USER ./do.sh`, it fails.

```
sudo -u A_USER ./do.sh'
```

which essentially runs:

```
sudo -u A_USER bash -c 'echo hi | tee /proc/self/fd/2'
```

outputs

```
tee: /proc/self/fd/2: Permission denied
hi
```

So far I have to following workaround:

```
sudo -u A_USER bash -c 'echo hi | tee >(cat >&2)'
```

I understand that this is for security reason: not share current user's pty to other users.

I'd like to know is there any option of `sudo -u A_USER` to let the process access its pty?

EDIT: I need put the `tee /proc/self/fd/2` or so into a script say do.sh, i.e., I can not put `tee /proc/self/fd/2` outside of the do.sh, so `sudo -u A_USER bash -c '...' | tee ...` will not be helpful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> sudo -u A_USER bash -c 'cmd | tee /dev/fd/2'
> ```

Or:

```
sudo -u A_USER sh -c 'cmd | tee /dev/fd/2'
```

as there's nothing bash-specific in there, would work on systems **other than** Linux or Cygwin.

While on most systems, opening `/dev/fd/x` is like doing `dup(x)`, like `>&x` in `sh`,  on Linux or Cygwin, `/dev/fd/x`, same as `/proc/self/fd/x` are only "magic" symlinks to the files opened on the corresponding file descriptors, so opening them doesn't get you the same behaviour as a `dup()` at all.

fd 2  may very well be open on a file you don't have permission to open for writing like in your case, or not be openable at all like a socket (as is typically the case for processes started by `systemd` where stderr is often a socket to `journald`).

Even if it's a regular file that you have write permission to, doing `tee /proc/self/fd/2` or `tee /dev/fd/2` is wrong as it opens the corresponding file from the start and truncates it. Even `tee -a /proc/self/fd/2` is wrong (though in practice is somewhat better) as while there's so truncation and it causes writes to be done at the end of the file, that's only valid if stderr is otherwise also opened in *append* mode.

For example, after:

```
(
  echo test | tee -a /proc/self/fd/2
  echo hi >&2
) 2> file
```

```
$ cat file
hi
t
```

The `hi` was output over the `test` written by `tee`.

On Linux/Cygwin, using `/dev/fd/x` / `/proc/self/fd/x` (or `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/stderr`) only works acceptably when the corresponding fd is open on some sorts of non-seekable files such as pipes or tty devices, but even then you can run into permission issues like here.

Your `tee >(cat >&2)` is transformed by your shell into some `tee /proc/self/fd/somefd` where `somefd` is opened on a pipe, and as the pipe has been created by the user that writes to it, there's no permission issue, but it's still wrong to do so in the bash shell specifically as bash does not wait for that `cat` process.

After:

```
(bash -c 'echo test | tee >(cat>&2)'; echo hi >&2) 2> file
```

You'll find that sometimes `file` contains:

```
hi
tee
```

Because `bash` has returned before `cat` has managed to write `test` and `echo` outputs its `hi` first.

Here, you can use `zsh` instead of `bash` which can do the teeing to several file descriptors as opposed to only files as with `tee` with:

```
sudo -u A_USER zsh -c 'echo hi >&1 >&2'
```

Where when a fd (here 1/stdout) is redirected more than once for output, it's redirected instead to a pipe to an internal process that does the teeing.

```
sudo -u A_USER zsh -c 'echo hi | tee >(cat >&2)'
```

Would work without bash's caveat above, but those `tee` and `cat` would be unnecessary as zsh has the feature builtin.

If `zsh` were the invoking shell, you could have that internal teeing done by the invoking user as opposed to USER_A with:

```
sudo -u A_USER sh -c 'echo hi' >&1 >&2
```

Which on Linux/Cygwin would be better than

```
sudo -u A_USER sh -c 'echo hi' | tee -a /dev/fd/2
```

Itself better than

```
sudo -u A_USER sh -c 'echo hi' | tee /dev/fd/2
```

(even though they also work around the permission issue) for the reasons mentioned above.

With `sh` (where you can't use process substitution) + `tee`, a solution to transform stderr into a pipe to work around the permission issue is to do it by hand with:

```
sudo sh -c '
  {
    {
      cmd |
        tee /dev/fd/2
    } 2>&1 >&3 3>&- |
      cat >&2 3>&-
  } 3>&1'
```

Where inside the inner command group, stderr becomes a pipe to `cat`, shared by `cmd`, though you could also leave `cmd`'s stderr alone with:

```
sudo sh -c '
  {
    {
      cmd 3>&- |
        tee /dev/fd/3
    } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- |
      cat >&2 4>&-
  } 4>&1'
```

Which would be a closer equivalent to your `cmd | tee >(cat >&2)` though here `cat` is properly waited for.

Comment: What's the difference between `/dev/fd/x` and `/proc/self/fd/x`? Both should be symlinks to the pts. If you fail opening `/proc/self/fd/x` for writing (because the pts is writable only by the original user), why does opening `/dev/fd/x` work?

Comment: `/dev/fd/x` and `/proc/self/fd/x` are the same on Linux and equally wrong to open there. Opening `/dev/fd/x` on other systems (which generally don't have `/proc/self/fd`) does the equivalent of `dup(x)` regardless of what files or non files fd x is open on, and there's no permission issue (though you can't open /dev/fd/x read-only if x is opened write-only for instance).

Comment: Oh, I was confused by your wording in your answer, but I see now that that's what you said. The fact you started the sentence with "would work" threw me off as I didn't expect the sentence to end with "on systems other than...". I would consider changing it to start "would not work on...", but maybe it's just me. So do you mean it would work on UNIX or FreeBSD?

Comment: @aviro, yes those `/dev/fd/x` were introduced on different Unix variants in the eighties, long before Linux. It should work in any Unix-like system that supports `/dev/fd/x` except those based on Linux or Cygwin AFAIK (note that UNIX is a trademark that can be used by any system that has been certified as compliant to SUS, which includes some Linux-based systems). On FreeBSD, `/dev/fd/x` support is optional and generally not enabled by default. /dev/fd/x are not specified by POSIX/SUS.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you so much, this is amazing. I will give it a try.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've tried the /dev/fd/2 solution, it does not work, the error is same: `tee: /dev/fd/2: Permission denied`. Your various insights are still worthy, so I gave you a credit, but without accepting it as an answer for now. Perhaps there is no graceful solution unless using zsh which is superior than bash. If you change your answer and note that the /dev/fd/2 may not work and present the zsh solution as main, then I will accept your answer. Meanwhile, I will update my question to clarify that I can not put the /proc/sef/fd/2 outside of the inner commands.

Comment: @osexp2000   I do say it does not work on Linux which is the main point of this answer: you can hardly use /dev/fd/x aka /proc/self/fd/x on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Just run `tee` as yourself.

Consider this command:

```
$ sudo -u A_USER bash -c 'ls -l *.txt  2>&1'
```

It sends lines of text to stdout.

There's no need to run `tee` as that other user.
Accept the lines and process them as yourself.
Invoke `sudo` again if you really need those permissions
later in the pipeline.

```
$ sudo -u A_USER bash -c 'ls -l *.txt  2>&1' | tee /proc/self/fd/2 | awk '{sum += $5}  END {print sum}'
```

---

If you hit a sticking point,
your script can always just write to the filesystem,
and then you `cat` or `tail -f` the text file in another process.

The text producer can always use
[stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf)
to adjust line buffering and display results promptly,
if desired.

Comment: Thanks. But I have a script, say a.sh, which need use `STD_OUT_STR=$(CMD ARGS ... 2>&1 | tee /proc/self/fd/2)`, it works well but not work under `sudo -u A_USER ./a.sh`. That is why I ask this question, I am not specially want to run the simple tee command itself.

Comment: I understand the `a.sh` requirement. It is not a sensible requirement to ask for. Given that `a.sh` lacks permission to write to fd/2, yet insists on writing to it, we don't anticipate that it's going to win. You want to change the Public API so the `a.sh` inputs and outputs allow it to win.